# Carousel - can't target the central image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with my carouse/slider, I've made it so previous and the next images take up 25% on each side, with the central image taking 50% width. The problem is that I was able to change the background of the left and right images but I can't seem to be able to apply the same color to the middle image. I've tried targeting pretty much all of the classes and ID's the carousel uses and I've run of out of ideas on how to target the central image:

[image]

Any advice is appreciated, here is the HTML:

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 border center-block">
            <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <img src="http://localhost/BlueQuote/wp-content/themes/blaskan/assets/images/lejla1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <img src="http://localhost/BlueQuote/wp-content/themes/blaskan/assets/images/lejla2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <img src="http://localhost/BlueQuote/wp-content/themes/blaskan/assets/images/lejla3.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.carousel-inner {
    width: 150%;
    left: -25%;
    background: rgba(248, 247, 216, 0.7);
}
.carousel-inner > .item.next, 
.carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-inner > .item.prev, 
.carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-control.left, 
.carousel-control.right {
    background: #002266;
    width: 25%;
}
.slider {
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 11;
    width: 105vw;
    border-top: 10px solid #fff7ea;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #fff7ea;
}
.col-xs-4 {
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
.carousel .item {
    background: #002266;
}
```

And jQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 4000
    })
    $('.carousel .item').each(function () {
        var next = $(this).next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        if (next.next().length > 0) {
            next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        } else {
            $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
});
```

Also here is the [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/mickey0001/pen/wpxJjq).

Comment: Do you not just need to target the `active` class?

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately it didn't do anything.

Comment: I'm confused. What is the color you want to change in the middle img? the borders? or you mean that semi-transparent blue overlay?

Comment: I mean the transparent blue overlay ( background: #002266;), I added it easily to both .carousel-control.left,  and.carousel-control.right But I couldn't figure out how to do the same with the middle image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the color declarations out of your side elements, and apply it to the whole container as follows:

```
.carousel-inner{position:relative;}

.carousel-inner:after {
    content:"";
    width: 100%; height:100%;
    background: rgba(0, 34, 102, 0.3);
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
}
```

That should create a semi-transparent blueish layer above everything